# ArrayList of numbers

Tags: java

I'm having trouble in my array. I want that everytime I click my "ButtonNew" memberId will automatically increase ex: 2012-000001 on my first click then 2012-0000002 on my second click (2012 is just the year today and "000001" is my array size). but of course i want that if i click again (ex: 2012-000003) then i cancelled the information(means that 2012-000003 didn't save in my database) my next click will still be 2012-000003 because i didn't save that. but how? do i really need arraylist here or count the number of rows in my database and then make it as size? here's my constructor:

```
    public Member() {
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("000000");
    int size=0;
    size= this.accounts.size()+1;
    this.setMemberId(""+yearToday + "-" + (formatter.format(size)));

}
```

i dont know how am i going to put  this.accounts.add(); because i dont know what to add. 
here's my ButtonNew action

```
    String last = "";
    Member memb = new Member();
    last = memb.getMemberId();
    this.txtMembersID.setText((last));
```

that's actually working but just displaying 2012-000001. means my array doesn't working pls. help.

Comment: where is your cancellation function.if its there then decrease the size value to -1 in cancel function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

and I think u need more java base.

```
public class Member {

    String memberId;

    public Member() {
        //generally we don't do to much things here.
    }

    //getters & setters
}

public class ArrayTest {

    public static final NumberFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("000000");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // put this accounts field out of your Member class
        List<Member> accounts = new ArrayList<Member>();
        // TODO fetch your data from database

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int size = accounts.size() + 1;
            Member member = new Member();
            member.setMemberId("" + 2012 + fmt.format(size));
            accounts.add(member);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is when i try this my output starts with 2012-000011? then             2012-000021
2012-000031
2012-000041
2012-000051
2012-000061
2012-000071
2012-000081
2012-000091
2012-000101

Comment: that's now working but if i close my program array restart into 2012-000001. i have my data base so how can i make it continuous array even if i close my program? example: my last is 2012-000004 then i close it and if i run again next is 2012-000005.

Comment: @rheighy for help u out, i need more code.

Comment: actually the code above is the code im working on, some codes of mine are for storing data in the database. what code you need sir?

Comment: @rheighy updated. pls have a try.

Comment: do u know how to get rowcount of table in mysql database and then make it as size? so that there will be no problem in arraylist. the last number of the row count will be the next number when click ButtonNew. ex: rowCount= 5 then next click id will be 2012-000006.

Comment: @rheighy common sql: `select count(*) from table` [mysql cout](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/count.php)

Comment: thanks. actually i know that but i encountered a lot of error. but now its working perfectly. thank u for your help.